# How do I disable or change ALT+Ctrl+K in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, hotkeys

I need to use `ATL+CTRL+K`. But it appears windows is using this hotkey for something, and I cant tell what it is used for.

I used this tool to figure out what was using it:

https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective/releases

It shows `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`, this is too general as that is explorer. But it shows that explorer is eating the key combination.

This page does not show anything associated with explorer.exe

https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-alt-k

But when pressing the combination in Windows nothing appears to happen.

- What does `ATL+CTRL+K` do in windows?
- Why does nothing happen?
- How do I disable it or remap it so I can use the key combination else where?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
It was the Kindle App I installed on windows.
How to disable `Ctrl + Alt + K`, found here [How to remove hotkey on Amazon Kindle PC that opens application](https://superuser.com/questions/1320544/how-to-remove-hotkey-on-amazon-kindle-pc-that-opens-application)

1. Open the start menu
2. Search for the Kindle app
3. Right click and select Open file location
4. Right click on the shortcut icon and select Properties.
5. Go to the "shortcut key" setting and press backspace to clear it out.
6. Click OK to save.